# How can i add days to a datetime field on a django model, using a IntegerField of the same model?

Tags: python, django, datefield

like i say in the title i need to fill automatically a field of my Django Model specifically a DateField adding X number of days that i specify in the same model form.

In my case i need to add the number of days taht i put in "total_days" to the date that i use in the field "start_day" and save the result on "end_day".

Here is the model:

```
class Certificate(models.Model):

    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    license_type = models.IntegerField(choices=LICENSE_TYPES, default=1)
    disease_type = models.IntegerField(choices=DESEASE_TYPES, blank=True, null=True)
    total_days = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    extra_days = models.PositiveIntegerField(Default=0)
    start_day = models.DateField()
    end_day = models.DateField(, editable=False)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor)
    diagnostic = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='certificates_created_by', editable=False)
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='certificates_modified_by', editable=False, blank=True, null=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "certificado"
        verbose_name_plural = "certificados"

    def __str__(self):
        pass
```

Well i try using "timedelta" but i can't use the start_day field because not detect this like a integer. And timedelta need a integer parameter.

Any Idea about how i can do this???

Now i'm doing this directly on the view and send the result on the context to the template. But the user needs to keep this from the first into the database.

Thanks very much!

Comment: First you don't want to add it in your model ! you must create a function like: def total_day(self): >>> return number of days !

Comment: Now How do you calculate total day ???

Comment: is not a calculate i put that manually in the form! is a doctor certificate, how much days of rest he give to a person. I have to put that number of days in the form (if the doctor put 4 days of rest i enter that number on total_days).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create get_end_date function and to which you can pass the start date as parameter. according to your coding convenience.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
start_date = datetime.strptime(start_day, "FORMAT") #start_day should be from your model and FORMAT as it is
end_day = start_date + timedelta(days=no_of_days_to_add)
end_date = end_day.strftime(end_day, <FORMAT>)
```

Comment: Yes but i need to save the end_date when i create a new object. In the Form i have to put the Start Day and the Total_days and when i put save! i need that the end_day automatically save the correct value (start_day + total_days) in the DB.

Comment: When processing your form you can call the function by passing start date and total days from form value as variable and function to return end date. Then you can save the value to database. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Ohh yes, i was doing something like that on my create view. but when i use the admin panel that not work.

Comment: For admin view you need to call the function in admin.py... Refer model admin objects in this https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: Yes i found this https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookNewformsAdminAndUser and i'm working on it